# Notepad++ replacing letters when I put anything infront

Tags: notepad++

This is a little hard to explain, but if I go back on some text and press space, it doesn't move the whole text it just replace the character in front of the place where I want to put space with a space. How do i stop it doing this?

This is basically making it almost impossible to fix code.

I have spent a little while fiddiling around in notepad++ but nothing seems to be doing anything useful, I am pretty sure its recently become like this, but I haven't used it in a couple of months.

PS. it is not just if I put a space, but any letter or number.

Below is a link to a youtube video that showcases my problem:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M261TBHtR9E

Comment: We are not mind reader. give an example.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Sounds like you've pressed the `insert` key on your keyboard accidentally and switched to *overwrite* mode. Check the bottom right corner of the screen - does it say `INS` (insert mode) or `OVR` (overwrite mode)?
Try pressing the `insert` key again to see if it fixes the problem. Alternatively, you can toggle overwrite/insert mode by clicking on the `OVR` or `INS` in the lower right corner.

Answer (score 4):

You might have replace mode on. Try pushing the `insert` key on your keyboard to switch modes.

Comment: You're right, i regret not just button mashing now :/

Answer (score 4):

On Bottom RIGHT you will see OVR which mean you in overwrite mode

Click on OVR you will be switched to Insert mode and you will see INS there.

Answer (score 1):

For HP laptop, press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>ins</kbd> keys.

Comment: For LENEVO too !

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is an "Insert" key right besides the "Delete" key on the keyboard, you need to pay attention to it while typing.
And on the lower right corner, there is the "IN" or "O" indicator shows "Insert" or "Overwrite". You can click it to switch modes.

Comment: This answer does not give any new information, it content is the same as the accepted answer. Just repeating the same information is not useful on this Q&A site. Adding a new answer to an old question is only useful if it add significant new information or a new insight into the problem. But welcome to Stack Overflow and please continue to add good question and good answers.

Answer (score 0):

On a Dell laptop it happens when you press the <kbd>ins</kbd> key (tiny letters above <kbd>prt sc</kbd>).
Press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>ins</kbd> and it will revert it.

Answer (score -1):

Press `Insert` key to disable overwrite mode.

Comment: This is the same as several other answers. It adds no new information and so is unhelpful. New answers to old questions should add new insights into the problem and its solutions.